# How to test value of a single field in a JSON object with RSpec

Tags: ruby, json, rspec, airborne

I am trying to use RSpec with the gem Airborne to test the value of a field in a JSON response of 'people' objects from an API.

Code:

```
  it 'GET list of people objects where gender = male' do
    get "/people?gender=male"
    expect_json('people.*', {gender: 'MALE'})
  end
```

So if my test makes an API call with this particular filter (gender), I expect to only pull back people with gender of male.  However this code fails, because every 'person' object has many different keys (:name, :age, etc.).  I ONLY want to test the gender, but I am unable to get it to pass because expect_json is expecting ALL of the keys in people to be written into the test.

I have combed through Google/Airborne documentation but to no avail:
https://github.com/brooklynDev/airborne

Comment: The docs say you're doing it right. Have you double checked that the response is actually correct? What's the json output itself?

Comment: So the json response for each person object is:
Person: {
       gender: "MALE",
       name: "John",
       age: 21
}

(There are actually many, many more keys but this is just an example)

Comment: Have double checked the response.  It lists all of the keys in the JSON and says that it doesnt match expected, and then in the 'Diff:' section lists the keys that I did not include in the test

Comment: Are you getting an array of people objects `people : [{person},{person}]` or an object of lots of people? `people: {{person},{person}}` ?

Comment: An array of people objects people `people : [{person},{person}]`

Comment: Welp I'm out of ideas and I haven't even tried anything yet.

Comment: Is this a requirement for you that you have to use this gem to test your JSON response? Or are you open to achieve the same goal without using this gem?

Comment: You need to share at least one sample JSON which has two or three persons, and also share the output of `rspec` output showing failure reasons. I am pretty sure that you are `path` is wrong and is not as per your JSON, as I tested the example of Airborne for given scenario - it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

This is place holder answer - to seek more details:

This [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brooklynDev/airborne/master/spec/test_responses/array_with_nested.json) produces below JSON from Airborne examples:

```
{
    "cars": [{
        "make": "Tesla",
        "model": "Model S",
        "owners": [
            {"name": "Bart Simpson"}
        ]
    }, {
        "make": "Lamborghini",
        "model": "Aventador",
        "owners": [
            {"name": "Peter Griffin"}

        ]
    }]
}
```

Here is an RSpec test (it uses a valid Internet URL, so anyone can try it out)

```
require 'airborne'

describe 'sample spec' do
  it 'should validate car make' do
    get 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brooklynDev/airborne/master/spec/test_responses/array_with_nested.json'
    expect_json('cars.*', make: 'Tesla')
  end
end
```

If you run the above test using `rspec <filename>.rb`, it will given error like below.  The error is expected as one of the JSON entry does not have `make` as `Tesla`.  However, the example demonstrates that Airborne has capability to look at single attribute across all nested JSON objects in a given JSON array.

```
E:\elixir>rspec fun.rb
F

Failures:

  1) sample spec should validate car make
     Failure/Error: expect_json('cars.*', make: 'Tesla')

       expected: "Tesla"
            got: "Lamborghini"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./fun.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 3.98 seconds (files took 0.68346 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./fun.rb:4 # sample spec should validate car make
```

Please update your question with sample JSON and RSpec output to show how your code is similar to above example,  as if it was, you should not have faced the issue.